# How to pass variable as key path to dict get in tcl?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have the following 'multi-dimensional' dictionary

```
dict set atm_prms bb N [dict create volume 13.3 radius 1.65 vdw_nrg -1.0906 ]
dict set atm_prms bb CA [dict create volume 9.4 radius 1.8 vdw_nrg -0.7708 ]
dict set atm_prms bb C [dict create volume 9.82 radius 1.4 vdw_nrg -0.8052 ]
dict set atm_prms bb O [dict create volume 8.2 radius 1.4 vdw_nrg -0.6724 ]
dict set atm_prms bb OXT [dict create volume 8.2 radius 1.4 vdw_nrg -0.6724 ]
dict set atm_prms ALA CB [dict create volume 16.15 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -1.3243 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG CB [dict create volume 12.77 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -1.0471 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG CG [dict create volume 12.77 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -1.0471 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG CD [dict create volume 12.77 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -1.0471 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG NE [dict create volume 9 radius 1.65 vdw_nrg -0.738 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG CZ [dict create volume 6.95 radius 1.4 vdw_nrg -0.5699 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG NH1 [dict create volume 9 radius 1.65 vdw_nrg -0.738 ]
dict set atm_prms ARG NH2 [dict create volume 9 radius 1.65 vdw_nrg -0.738 ]
dict set atm_prms ASN CB [dict create volume 12.77 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -1.0471 ]
dict set atm_prms ASN CG [dict create volume 9.82 radius 1.9 vdw_nrg -0.8052 ]
dict set atm_prms ASN OD1 [dict create volume 8.17 radius 1.4 vdw_nrg -0.6699 ]
dict set atm_prms ASN ND2 [dict create volume 13.25 radius 1.65 vdw_nrg -1.0865 ]
```

How can I use a key path stored in a variable to retrieve a value?

For instance, this works:

```
> puts [dict get $atm_prms ALA CB volume]
16.15
```

But this fails:

```
> set my_path {ALA CB volume}
> puts [dict get $atm_prms $my_path]
key "ALA CB volume" not known in dictionary
```

How do I properly use a key path that is stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"ALA CB volume"` is being substituted into the `dict get` command as *a single word*. You need to tell Tcl that you want that list expanded into separate words:

```
% puts [dict get $atm_prms $my_path]
key "ALA CB volume" not known in dictionary
% puts [dict get $atm_prms {*}$my_path]
16.15
```

See rule #5 in http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Excellent! This language takes some getting used to... Lol.

Comment: True, but consider the entire language has only 12 syntax rules. Grok those and you're golden.

Comment: That's precisely the part that takes getting used to. :-P